# Does Rust optimize for loops over calculated ranges?

Tags: optimization, rust, micro-optimization

As an exercise I'm trying to micro-optimize code in Rust 1.3.0. I have a loop of a loop over an array. Something like this:

```
loop {
    for i in 0..arr.len() {
        // something happens here
    }
}
```

Since arrays are fixed size in Rust, will the compiler optimize the code by evaluating `arr.len()` just once and reusing the value, or will the expression be evaluated with each pass of the top-level loop? The question can be expanded to more calculation-heavy functions without side-effects, other than `arr.len()`.

In other words, would the above code be equivalent to this:

```
let arr_len = arr.len();

loop {
    for i in 0..arr_len {
        // something happens here
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you are interested in optimization, it's usually a good idea to try and use an iterator instead of indexing into the slice, which has a bit of overhead for bounds checks. Use `for v in &arr` instead when possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `..` is a range operator, which forms a [`Range<Idx>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/struct.Range.html) object (or a derivative: `RangeFrom`, `RangeFull` or `RangeTo`). Those objects only contain indexes (the `Idx` type), so you can rest assured that `.len()` is only evaluated once.

---

In general, it is a good idea to inspect the LLVM IR. If you have a synthetic example, you can use the playground easily enough. For [example](https://gist.github.com/2d6f71579140a043ebe8):

```
// A black-box prevents optimization, and its calls are easy to spot.
extern {
    fn doit(i: i32) -> ();
}

fn main() {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for i in 0..arr.len() {
        unsafe { doit(arr[i]); }
    }
}
```

Yields the following function:

```
; Function Attrs: uwtable
define internal void @_ZN4main20hd87dea49c835fe43laaE() unnamed_addr #1 {
entry-block:
  tail call void @doit(i32 1)
  tail call void @doit(i32 2)
  tail call void @doit(i32 3)
  tail call void @doit(i32 4)
  tail call void @doit(i32 5)
  ret void
}
```

In this case, with a fixed length, there is no loop at all: it has been unrolled.

Comment: This is essentially similar to the answer I had before editing, in response to Benjamin Lindley's comment.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I am afraid I never saw the previous version of your answer :/

Answer (score 3):

At least in a quick check with using `arr.len()` nested inside another loop, no code seems to be generated for the "call" to `arr.len()` at all. In the generated code, the size of the array is simply hard-coded into the output.

In other words, I would not expect your second snippet to execute any faster than the first one.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to multiple executions of the entire for loop body, whereas you are addressing (correct me if I'm wrong) the iterations of a single execution of the for loop. In other words, he wants to know if, each time the for loop begins, if the range extents are calculated again, even though they cannot change (because the array length cannot change). Notice his for loop is nested in another loop.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, that's exactly what I meant.